# How do I have Excel create a list of items that have and "X" in an indicated column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a way in Excel to generate list of people that have read a procedure on a second sheet. In the table we are reading the people who have done it are indicated with an "X" next to their name

For example (These are not real names):

| Name | Procedure 001 Read | Procedure 002 Read |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob Smith |  | X |
| Jeff Smith |  |  |
| Alan Jones | X |  |
| Scott Rogers |  |  |
| Nick Davis | X |  |

I would want the results to be:

| Procedure 001 | Procedure 002 |
| --- | --- |
| Alan Jones | Bob Smith |
| Nick Davis |  |

I tried using lookup and vlookup functions, but I could not figure out how to make them do what I was expecting.

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are just needing to see the list, you could set a filter on the table and then filter out the blanks for each procedure. The resulting name column would then be everyone having read that procedure (or reverse the filter and you have a list of those who haven't done it yet). No formulas required for this.

Comment: I was originally going to go that route but I was _advised_ that having the results on a separate sheet is what I need to aim for.

Comment: If you use the `Advanced Filter`, you can have the results on a separate sheet

Comment: Perhaps a hidden helper column for each procedure that generates a count of the X's in the original column down to that point (so the Xs are essentially numbered in the helper column), and then an Index/Match formula to look for each number and return the name.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld When I tried the Advanced Filter it would not let me copy to another sheet.

Comment: @chickenjones44 The **trick** is to select the Advanced Filter while the page to which you want to copy results is the active sheet. Then you can select the actual data sheet for the List and Criteria ranges, and that other sheet for your results. But I've provided a formula solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Filter Data Into Groups (Lists)

```
=LET(Names,A2:A6,Values,B2:G6,Criteria,"X",
    DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Values)),LAMBDA(Result,cCol,
IFERROR(HSTACK(Result,FILTER(Names,INDEX(Values,,cCol)=Criteria,"")),""))),,1))
```

[image]

If you want the input to be `A1:G6` and copy the same headers, you can do:

```
=LET(Data,A1:G6,Criteria,"X",
    Names,TAKE(DROP(Data,1),,1),Values,DROP(DROP(Data,1),,1),
    VSTACK(DROP(TAKE(Data,1),,1),
    DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Values)),LAMBDA(Result,cCol,
IFERROR(HSTACK(Result,FILTER(Names,INDEX(Values,,cCol)=Criteria,"")),""))),,1)))
```

Comment: Whenever there is a procedure with no one having read it I get weird results. I added a name for no one having read the procedure. But is there a way to make it work if no one has read the procedure? If not it works and I greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't test it properly. The 3rd parameter of the `FILTER` function should be `""`: In the last line, right after `Criteria`, add `,""` . It's corrected now.

Answer (score 3):

Using Structured References with table name = `Table1`

For the Header Row:

`=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(Table1[#Headers],1,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(Table1)-1,2))," Read","")`

For the Columns (*and fill across as needed*)

```
=FILTER(Table1[[Name]:[Name]],Table1[Procedure 001 Read]="X")
```

***Original***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have dynamic arrays then you can also do this the old-fashioned way

[image: screenshot illustrating legacy-formula approach]

the formula in cell A2 of Sheet2 is

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6,AGGREGATE(14,4,(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6="X")*(ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6))-1,ROW()-1))
```

which can be copied across and down.

The formula *can* be wrapped in an `IFERROR()` function and copied across and down for each employee *or*, you could use conditional formatting (as applied to A1:B1 of Sheet2)
[image: screenshot illustrating conditional-formatting formula]

to indicate *when* you need to copy the formula down further
(in the screenshot the red colouring indicates that the formula in A2 needs to be copied down to A3)